# Huge latency on https websockets (wss)

Tags: java, ssl, cloudflare, latency, java-websocket

I'm working on a mmo browser game called mope.io (The game is live at https://mope.io) - we recently added https support, but have noticed a HUGE amount of latency over wss websockets. On many of our game servers with https (the issue seems to happen randomly to some servers), there is a delay of several seconds on wss that wasn't seen before on ws.

Quick info: our game server sends 10 update packets per second, giving info on what changed in-game.

We use cloudflare for our site (setting Full:Strict), through our own wildcard certificate (*.mope.io). All of our game servers have matching DNS records which fall under this certificate (so that the websockets can work over https- we connect to eg. wss://server1.mope.io:7020 instead of ws://1.2.3.4:7020).
The game servers are written in Java, using the following library: https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket

Any ideas on reasons that websockets could perform so terribly slow under wss/tls? This even happens when I'm the only one connected to the server. Any help/guidance is greatly appreciated :)

Extra info: I've noticed a 11s time-to-first-byte for the first https request when connecting to the site, before cloudflare cached it, what could cause this!?

Comment: You are the mope.io dev?

Comment: Have you done any network sniffing to make sure there aren't other packets flooding the server?

Comment: Yes, this is clickstan, the mope.io lead dev

Comment: efekctive, At the moment, no, I'm going to have to find a reproducable test case, and debug this to find the exact point in the library where this big delay occurs

Comment: Did you never find a solution for this? (I notice mope.io isn't https as of now). Having the same issue with my .io game - I happen to be using Java and the same WebSocket library haha. I think it may be an unsolvable issue of TLS not really being designed for the frequency that .io games operate at. My game has a login so the site's explicitly marked as insecure, too..

Comment: I didnt, I just disabled https for now

Answer (score 1):

My friend had similar problem in his **Node.js** wss game server and he suspected that it was DoS attack. He managed to reproduce the "freezing" in his server with just single computer by opening fastly WSS connections. I am not sure if this affects only secure websocket servers or both insecure and secure.

Problem occurred on both **WS** and **UWS** library.
In **websockets/ws** library, lag happened even when rejecting the connections on `verifyClient()` to prevent it ever getting into applications own connection handling logic (which could be reasonable explanation for the lag) so I wonder could the bottleneck be somewhere in Nodes underlying socket stuff with handling secure connections.

Our solution to prevent the freezing was to setup iptables with rate limit. Replace 1234 with your server port.

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 1234 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 1234 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 1 --hitcount 2 -j DROP
```

That will allow 2 connections in second per IP address. Also save iptables if necessary since its resets on system restart.

https://serverfault.com/questions/296838/traffic-filtering-for-websockets

https://debian-administration.org/article/187/Using_iptables_to_rate-limit_incoming_connections